# I want to convert the encrypted user login creds to tamil language and store in mysqll db

Tags: php, validation, character-encoding, credentials, utf

So im going to create a login website where the collected user creds are stored in a mysql db  for validation but the difference is that the aldready encrypted password must be encoded in tamil

Can anyone give me a overview about his and where to get started

Comment: _"must be encoded in tamil"_ - really unclear what that is supposed to mean. A language spoken by humans, is not an "encoding".

Comment: Passwords must be _hashed_, not encrypted.  PHP provides specialist functions for this - see [How to use PHP's password_hash to hash and verify passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords) . And if your password is hashed correctly, then its original encoding is largely irrelevant as far as I can see. Also, like CBroe I cannot make sense of the phrase "encoded in Tamil". Perhaps you would like to [edit] your question and clarify precisely what you are trying to tell us. See also [ask] for tips on asking good questions here